# Cannot call bash function inside makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

I have an impression that I can call bash function inside GNU makefile, but seems wrong. Here is a simple test, I have this function defined:

```
>type lsc
lsc is a function
lsc () 
{ 
    ls --color=auto --color=tty
}
```

Here is my Makefile:

```
>cat Makefile
all:
    lsc
```

Here is what I get in running make:

```
>make
lsc
make: lsc: Command not found
make: *** [all] Error 127
```

Is my impression wrong? Or is there any env setup issue? I can run "lsc" at the command line.

Comment: Another piece of information: When I try to reproduce this, I add the command `type lsc` to the rule, and it gives the correct answer-- but the command `lsc` still fails.

Answer (score 12):

Use `$*` in your BASH script:

**functions.sh**

```
_my_function() {
  echo $1
}

# Allows to call a function based on arguments passed to the script
$*
```

**Makefile**

```
test:
    ./functions.sh _my_function "hello!"
```

Running example:

```
$ make test
./functions.sh _my_function "hello!"
hello!
```

Answer (score 10):

You cannot call bash functions or aliases in a Makefile, only binaries and scripts. What you can do however, is calling an interactive bash and instruct it to call your function or alias:

```
all:
    bash -i -c lsc
```

if `lsc` is defined in your `.bashrc`, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Did you export your function with "export -f"?

Is bash the shell of your Makefile, or is is sh?

Comment: Yes, I tried "export -f", not help.  Not sure your 2nd question mean, my shell is bash and I run make in it.

Comment: Did you set the SHELL variable? See here: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html#Choosing-the-Shell "If this variable is not set in your makefile, the program /bin/sh is used as the shell."

Answer (score 1):

You can import all shell scripts functions from a shell file if you use this from the question [How do I write the 'cd' command in a makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789594/how-do-i-write-the-cd-command-in-a-makefile)

```
.ONESHELL: my_target

my_target: dependency
    . ./shell_script.sh
    my_imported_shell_function "String Parameter"
```

If you like, you can also even do not use the `.ONESHELL` thing and do it all in one line just by using a colon `;` right after the importing the shell script:

```
my_target: dependency
    . ./shell_script.sh; my_imported_shell_function "String Parameter"
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose compile is a function in you .bash_profile

.bash_profile

```sh
compile(){
  ...
}
```

Makefile

```
ACTIVE_ENV=source ~/.bash_profile 
default:
    $(ACTIVE_ENV) && compile boot_sect_simple.asm c
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is not unique to `make`.  Make executes commands in the context of a shell, and that shell can execute functions *if they've been made available*.

The problem is that when you launch a new shell (or shell script, or make command), [Bash doesn't automatically forward all functions from the calling environment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63665/how-to-define-a-bash-function-that-can-be-used-by-different-scripts).

Explicitly specifying that the shell should be `/bin/bash` ensures that make won't invoke a different shell interpreter, which could affect function handling.  [There are a couple ways of doing this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/589300/86967)  In the examples below, I use the targeted-specific approach.

As an example, the below makefile snippets invoke [`nvm`](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) [which is implemented as a collection of bash functions](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/issues/806).

*WARNING: Using previously-defined functions means the makefile depends on the (potentially uncontrolled) state of your shell environment, so this type of solution should be used judiciously.*

---

### Method 1: Run an "interactive" shell

In this example, the functions are assumed to be defined as part of a users's .bashrc file.  Running Bash in interactive mode (with `-i`) causes .bashrc to be processed into the command environment.

```
mytarget1: SHELL:=/bin/bash -i
mytarget1:
    nvm install 14 && npm version
```

---

### Method 2: Import the functions on demand

This approach explicitly sources the script that defines the functions of interest.

```
mytarget2:
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install 14 && npm version
```

For this, you might prefer:
[Multi-line bash commands in makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121182/multi-line-bash-commands-in-makefile/29085684#29085684)

---

### Method 3: Export the function before running makefile

Invoke `make` with: `export -f nvm ; make mytarget3` to export the function to any sub-commands.

```
mytarget3: SHELL:=/bin/bash
mytarget3:
    nvm install 14 && npm version
```

*Note: This example won't work fully because `nvm`, internally, relies on a large collection of sub-functions which would also need to be exported.*

Comment: Method 4: declare the function inline as part of a [multi-line bash command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10121182/multi-line-bash-commands-in-makefile/29085684#29085684). Don't forget `SHELL=bash`.

Comment: Scripting `nvm` is a pain. [nvm command not available in bash script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184508/6764)