# cd.. works without ONESHELL in Makefile

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, gnu-make

From [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html), it is necessary to add a `target` in `.ONESHELL` to make all the commands run in a same sub-shell process. Further discussion on that is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789594/how-do-i-write-the-cd-command-in-a-makefile?noredirect=1&lq=1).

This is my `makefile`,

```
.PHONY: clean build
.ONESHELL: deploy

zip := my.zip

clean:
    cd ..
    rm -f $(zip)

build: clean
    npm install .
    zip -r ../$(zip) . \
        --exclude=package-lock.json \
        --exclude=.gitignore \
        --exclude=makefile \
        --exclude=*.git* 

... more lines
```

So when I do `make build`, the zip file in the parent folder gets created. And when I do `make clean`(from the same directory) the zip is removed too from the parent folder. What I don't understand it since `cd ..` runs in an independent shell process, how does the zip in parent folder gets removed with the `make clean` command, since it is not included in `.ONESHELL`?

Version: GNU Make 4.1 on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.ONESHELL` doesn't accept prerequisites (or more accurately, it ignores them).  If you define it, it's enabled for the entire makefile.  It's currently not possible to specify `.ONESHELL` only for individual targets.

The GNU make manual says:

> If the `.ONESHELL` special target appears anywhere in the makefile then *all*
> recipe lines for each target will be provided to a single invocation of the shell.

And just in case you're wondering:  this applies to included makefiles -- if any one of the set specifies `.ONESHELL:`, every recipe in all of them will have it applied.