# Visualize subshells/processes for command

Tags: shell, process, cd, subshell

Sometimes shell commands behave unexpectedly because of subshells-processes.

A recent example I experienced was that this command won't work [because xargs runs the `cd`-command](https://superuser.com/questions/206789/using-xargs-to-cd-to-a-directory) in a subshell:

```
ls | sort | tail -1 | xargs cd
```

Another one is that `cd` [doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789594/how-do-i-write-the-cd-command-in-a-makefile) in Makefiles.

Is there a way to visualize which shells/subshells/processes do what in a (chained) command? I would like to get a better feeling for them.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following utility could help to debug pipe statements:

```sh
function _() {
  local code=0
  "$@" || code=$? > >(tee -a "$1".out) 2> >(tee -a "$1".err >&2)
  echo Exited with "$code" >> "$1".out
}
```

Usage:

```sh
_ ls | _ sort | _ tail -1 | xargs _ cd
```